# PostgreSQL - How can I manage WAL archiving for different databases on a server?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.1

I'd like to use WAL archiving for incremental backup of my database. But I have 2 databases on my server, and I can't afford the disc space for backup of both of them. So I only want to backup one of them. I didn't find anything about multiple databases in PostgreSQL documentation or anywhere else. Or I didn't find anything about specifying the database name for WAL backup.
It will be appreciated if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. WAL archiving can only be done for the whole Postgres cluster.

Comment: I would suggest that disk space is relatively cheap. But it's a trade off between that and effective usage of your server's memory if you go down the route of running multiple clusters.

Comment: @Colin'tHart 9.3 should improve the memory trade-off somewhat, now that Pg can use `mmap()`ed anonymous memory instead of System V shared memory for `shared_buffers`.

Comment: For people reading this in future when 9.3 is released :-)

Comment: @Colin'tHart Or those nuts enough to run it now when it's still undergoing rapid catalog version increments. Yes, in future when it's released it should improve things; 'till then the shared memory split is going to hurt.

Comment: May running two separate PG instances/clusters be a solution?

Comment: As Craig explained in the following answer it would be a solution. But I'm still searching for some easier solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't split WAL archiving out so one database goes in one WAL archive stream and other DBs go in another WAL archive stream. A single write-ahead log is shared by all databases in a PostgreSQL server ("cluster" in PostgreSQL parlance). All databases managed by a postmaster have the same WAL. This is a sometimes unfortunate limitation of the current replication/PITR/archiving design and is true for the in-development-at-time-of-writing 9.3 and all and prior releases.

If you want to separate the WAL archiving, you have to separate the databases into different clusters. You can do this by running more than one instance of PostgreSQL on a server; they simply have to have different data directories and different listening ports. Some packagings of PostgreSQL provide built-in tools to do this, like the [`pg_wrapper`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html) tool used on Debian and Ubuntu, which has [`pg_createcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html). Alternately, you can always just use [`initdb`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html) to create a cluster and [`pg_ctl`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html) to start the cluster after editing the new cluster's `postgresql.conf` to set an appropriate port.

Tools like [pgbouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) may be used, if desired, to multiplex the multiple clusters transparently, so pgbouncer listens on port 5432 (the default Pg port) and decides which server to send the connection to based on which database it asks for. Generally it's easier to just specify a port in the connection setup of the applications that use each database, though.

On PostgreSQL 9.2 and below you must allocate each server an exclusive, non-overlapping shared memory region for its `shared_buffers`. One server cannot make use of the other server's `shared_buffers` space when the other server is not busy. That means you *are* wasting some system resources. [PostgreSQL 9.3 improves this](http://www.depesz.com/2012/07/12/waiting-for-9-3-dramatically-reduce-system-v-shared-memory-consumption/) by allocating `shared_buffers` out of anonymous memory, giving the OS more freedom about how it manages it.

If you don't want to run multiple clusters, you can use [alternative replication or backup solutions based on out-of-tree tools like Slony-I, Bucardo, etc](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) to manage your data replication and archival.

Comment: According to what I read (http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Warm_Standby), other PITR tools are using the WAL system themselves. So I think they do not offer any solution to my problem with 2 databases. So what is the advantage of using them for my database incremental backup instead of setting up the WAL archiving myself?

Comment: @Sina Where did I suggest using warm standby? I pointed out row-level replication tools like Bucardo and Slony-I.

Comment: I had problem finding anything related to PITR in Slony-I and Bucardo documentations. It will be great if you help me with this. And also which way do you recommend? Seperating databases into different clusters and using the wal backup of the postgre, or using some other tool?

Comment: @Sina Re Bucardo and Slony, see this page I linked to above: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Replication . As for how to do it: Slony-I is complicated, I don't advise using it unless you really know you need it. Bucardo is great when you're just replicating a few tables, but isn't as good if you need to replicate DDL changes or lots of tables. Splitting the cluster and using built-in streaming replication is best if you need it simple or you have several DBs or lots of tables or lots of DDL to replicate.